# Low-res GUI for Linux on a RaspberryPi used as a mobile device

Tags: linux, hardware, gui, mobile, touch-screen

I want to build a custom mobile device using a RaspberryPi or BananaPi and a touchscreen (resolution 320x240). Is there GUI for Linux that's made to work well on such low resolutions, preferably touchscreen capable but not a necessity?